# Rewriting a solr query before parsing it

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm working on a simple query rewriter that makes some changes to the query string. The query rewriter should change the query string before the query is parsed or sent to other Solr nodes. What is the most suitable Solr mechanism to use for such a code? Currently I'm writing a custom search component to do the job. The component modifies the value of the original `q` parameter in the component's `prepare` method. It works, but I'm wondering whether Solr has a mechanism designed for that.

I'm not implementing it as a custom query parser because the query rewriting process might be time consuming, so I don't want it to be executed for each and every shard.

Does Solr have built-in a mechanism for query rewriting?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way AFAIK is to use [`QParserPlugin`](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins).

However, if you are using Solr via HTTP, maybe you can solve this by rewriting the URL?

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a bad idea.  Anytime you change the query you are effectively "parsing" it and are taking on the full responsibility of the query parsers to do it right.  You may as well do it properly within a custom query parser.  How is the query rewriting process that time consuming?  It's likely not worth worrying about... that's what scaling is for.

Comment: The query rewriting process is time consuming because in order to do its job, the rewriter retrieves data from an external source.